# How can I edit the text in WooCommerce /my-account/

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I edit the text in WooCommerce /my-account/? From your account dashboard, you can view your recent orders, manage your ( Shipping and billing addresses ), and edit your password and account details.

I would like to change it from Shipping and billing addresses to ( Delivery and billing addresses )

Current text: From your account dashboard you can view your recent orders, manage your ( Shipping and billing addresses) and edit your password and account details.

Change the text to: From your account dashboard you can view your recent orders, manage your ( Delivery and billing addresses) and edit your password and account details.

Answer (score 2):

Copy paste /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/my-account/dashboard.php
into /wp-content/themes/{{yourtheme}}/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php 
edit the line which shows the content.

Answer (score 2):

**Login to the server via FTP or go to Cpanel -> File Manager**

1. Create a folder “woocommerce” inside your theme folder
2. Create another new folder “myaccount” inside the “woocommerce” folder
3. Go to plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount and copy the dashboard.php file
4. Paste this file into yourthemefolder/woocommerce/myaccount folder
5. Now edit the text and save the file